# java boolean method not returning true/false?

Tags: java

In an example in class we were given this method as part of a bigger problem:

```
  public boolean isWinner()
{
    return ((points == 4) || (score == 4));

}
```

My impression of boolean type methods was that they HAVE to return true/false like "return true;" In this example there is no where indicating whether it is returning true/false so if points == 4 does it return true? and if score ==4 does it return false? or is it if either are true then the entire return statement is true?

Comment: Do you know or the logical OR (`||`) operator behave?

Comment: In Java, a boolean _is_ either `true` or `false`. And your method above does that. If it didn't it wouldn't compile.

Comment: who downvoted my question o.O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If either `points == 4` or `score == 4` is true, the whole thing will be true. All boolean expressions evaluate down to either true or false.

This expression:

```
return ((points == 4) || (score == 4));
```

Will either return true or false.

Answer (score 2):

`||` is the OR operator. Which for two expressions has the following truth table:

```
T T = T
T F = T
F T = T
F F = F
```

So if both `points` and `score` are `false` then the function will return false. Otherwise it will return true.

Answer (score 1):

```
return ((points == 4) || (score == 4));
```

Execution of above will result in `return true` or `return false`

From [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1).

> The value produced by the == operator is true if the value of the left-hand operand is equal to the value of the right-hand operand; otherwise, the result is false.

also read about `||` operation in [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24) I hope that will clear your doubts

Answer (score 1):

This

```
return (points == 4) || (score == 4);
```

is the same as

```
boolean ret = (points == 4) || (score == 4);
return ret;
```

which is the same as

```
if (points == 4) return true;
if (score == 4) return true;
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Java truth tables for || and &&. This will help give you an understanding of boolean results.
As your question stands, it will return true if **either** of those statements are true and false if they are both false.

Comment: Why don't you explain "Java truth tables for || and &&" instead of suggesting that the reader looks at it.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one exception in that code.
In the case that points/score are Integer referencing null, would cause an exception.

```
public class Snippet {
    private Integer points;
    private Integer score;

    public boolean isWinner() {
        return ((points == 4) || (score == 4));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Snippet().isWinner());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at snippet.Snippet.isWinner(Snippet.java:8)
    at snippet.Snippet.main(Snippet.java:13)
```

Comment: While this is true, it really doesn't have much to do with the question, which was about using boolean expressions vs. the boolean literals `true` and `false` as the return value from boolean methods.